# Symfony inbuilt server running for a different project

Tags: php, symfony

I created a new Symfony project using composer as below.

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

And the Symfony inbuilt web server runs on http://localhost:8000/ as below.

> Welcome to Symfony 3.1.4
>
> Your application is now ready. You can start working on it at: C:\Projects\my_project_name/

Now I created my original new project eventplanner. But the web server is still running for the old project my_project_name as above.

I tried stop server and start server. But that doesn't help. Could someone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hacky way to do this as, I didn't receive any suggestions so far. I used a different port for this new project eventplanner and able to access it through http://localhost:8001/.